# Advanced image hotlinking protection

Tags: javascript, image, .htaccess

I want to make some advanced hotlinking protection for images on my site. And I want the thieves suffer so I would like that any user that goes to thieves site that is trying to hotlink my image to be redirected to my site.

Let's say I have an image on `imagedomain.com` named `harmless.png`

Thief takes my image and on `stealerdomain.net` he simply puts

```
<img src='http://imagedomain.com/harmless.png'>
```

and he steals my image. I know how to prevent this from happening, I already have htaccess code that prevents hotlinking of images:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^$  
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http(s)?://imagedomain.com [NC]   
RewriteRule \.(jpg|jpeg|png|gif)$ http://imagedomain.com [NC,R,L]
```

This nice code prevents thieves from displaying my images on their site. Its'good but what I really want is that when some thief puts `<img>` with `src` that is pointing to my image then everyone who displays that `<img>` tag via his browser would be redirected to my site (as a punishement cuz its me who should get a traffic for that image content not the stealer).

Does anyone knows how to do this?

Comment: Fortunately, this is impossible. You can't redirect a page from inside an image resource.

Comment: I thought that when you can do this with an iframe (when someone is iframing your website and stealing your content) that you can do this with an image too?

Comment: There really is no point to try and "punish" the person. If it's blocked they aren't getting the image anyway. Also you can create an image and put whatever you want on it and display that instead of your real image if they try to hotlink something. Like this `RewriteRule \.(jpg|jpeg|png|gif)$ http://imagedomain.com/hotlink.gif [NC,R,L]`